# How to solve a general equation using Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

`Solve[x^2 + 2x^2 + 2x + 1 == 0, x]`

Can anyone suggest how this or any general polynomial equation of any degree could be solved using Mathematica?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking--`Solve` takes an equation and solves it. Type that in.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html

Answer (score 0):

Just enter the question in a Mathematica notebook and press shift + enter. You may also want to try `NSolve` which provides numerical solutions. `Solve` gives exact solutions to equations (if there are any)

`NSolve[x^2 + 2x^2 + 2x + 1 == 0, x]`

The output is:

```
{{x -> -0.333333 - 0.471405 I}, {x -> -0.333333 + 0.471405 I}}
```